# Why can not display Views?

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, view

I'am using ExtJS 5.1.1 and exercising on another demo application based on MVC pattern.

What is wrong with bootstrapping? **Menu panel** is not displaying and not printing message to it's `console.log`!

File structure of demo-app;

```
index.html
app.js

app/
  view/
  -- DBMainView
  -- DBMenuPanel
```

**app.js:**

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
    views: ['DBMainView', 'DBMenuPanel'],
    name: 'MultiDB',

    launch: function () {
        console.log('this is app.js');
        Ext.create('MultiDB.view.DBMainView');
    }
});
```

**DBMainView.js**:

```
Ext.define('MultiDB.view.DBMainView', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    alias: 'widget.dbmainview',
    requires: [
        'MultiDB.view.DBMenuPanel',
        'Ext.panel.Panel'
    ],

    layout: 'border',
    split: true,

    items: [{
        xtype: 'dbmenupanel',
        region: 'west'
    }],

    initComponent: function () {
        console.log('this is main view');
    }
});
```

**DBMenuPanel.js**:

```
Ext.define('MultiDB.view.DBMenuPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.dbmenupanel',
    width: 150,
    collapsed: true,
    collapsible: true,

    initComponent: function () {
        console.log('this is menu view');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `this.callParent();` in the `initComponent` method. You can override [initComponent](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-initComponent), but you always must call the parent method, so that the component properly initializes.

> The initComponent method must contain a call to callParent in order to
>   ensure that the parent class' initComponent method is also called.

Comment: Dear @scebotari66 thank you for your time.. now it's working fine! BTW I've added `this.callParent(arguments);` to both view *(MainView, MenuPanel)* and then it has worked. As well I tried to added only on MainView class but it gave this error: `[W] XTemplate evaluation exception: Cannot read property 'items' of null` I hope, I did the right setting?

Comment: Yes, you need `this.callParent` for both classes. When you have added only to the main view, you got the error because the menu panel have not been initialized properly, and the main view could not identify it as a child component. You can skip the `arguments` param, because the function has no arguments.